# Execute one process for 30 seconds and get the output

Tags: java, android, process, timeout, execute

I need to run a process for 30 seconds and while it is running I have to store the output in a text file. After 30 seconds I'd have to destroy the process. I know how to run the process and how to store data in a file but don't know how to do it for 30 seconds only (the process would take much longer if not stopped).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my_long_command & sleep 30 && kill %+
```

<strike>(Still need to make sure %1 will always reference that job, I'm checking how)</strike>

P.S I'm assuming you're talking about shell command execution? The answer I gave works in bash

**EDIT**: Changed %1 to %+

Comment: I dont want exec the command in a shell. I'm executing the binary application with a Process object in android source code ( Java ). I'm taking a Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path+binary executable) to run a process for 30 seconds and while it is running I have to store the output in a text file.

Comment: Ok, there was hardly any context for me to get that. I've retagged your question.